# Vue - conditional attribute binding

Tags: vuejs2

I am making a form in a Vue component and would like to set the HTML attribute `required` to an input field based on the value I am having in an object property.
So, for the example, an object that has fields like this:

```
label:"Name"
required:"1"
type:"textbox"
```

I need to a set the field to have `required` attribute in an input tag:

```
<input class="input is-large" :type="input.type" required>
```

And for the ones that don't have 1 as a value for that field I don't want a `required` attribute. 
How can I do that in Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<input class="input is-large" :type="input.type" :required="obj.required == 1">
```

Since your object's `required` property has `1` as a string not number I used `==` for comparison so that equality is tested after coercion